# in ESE, can I use JET_coltypDateTime safely to hold an unsigned 64 bit value?

Tags: database, windows, winapi, extensible-storage-engine

I'm using ESE on an older OS (JET_VERSION = 0x0501).  I need to store an unsigned 64 int

can I safely cast this int to a JET_coltyDateTime or JET_coltypCurrency?   am I missing anything, does ESE do any kind of conversion/limits on the ranges?

note that for my purposes sorting order doesnt matter unless it somehow messes up the ability to search

Answer (score 1):

That will work. The data is stored as a 64-bit value internally and only handled in a type-specific way when it comes to indexing. You will get a strange sort order, but would be able to do exact-value searches.